# How to create table and pagination in index page?

Tags: php

How should I create a table for my retrieved data from database, and how can I create pagination in that page?

I have used for list but I need a table format and pagination also needs it. I have only 5 records per page.

```
<?php  
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/article.php');
$article = new Article;  
$articles = $article->fetch_all();

//print_r($articles);   
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css"/>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
            <ol>
                <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
                    
                    <li><a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $article['article_title']; ?>            
                        </a>
                        <small>
                    posted <?php echo date('l jS Y', $article['article_timestamp']); ?>
                </small>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ol>
            <br />
            <small><a href="admin">admin</a></small>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work for your project, I recommend you to learn about HTML components it will help you a lot.

A tables needs a Head and Body, this is the basic table format:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>TITLE 1</th>
        <th>TITLE 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>VALUE FOR TITLE 1</td>
            <td>VALUE FOR TITLE 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And your code ends like this.

```
<?php  
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;

$articles = $article->fetch_all();

//print_r($articles); 

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css"/>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Link</th>
                        <th>Posted</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($articles as $key => $article): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $article['article_title']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo date('l jS Y', $article['article_timestamp']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
            <small><a href="admin">admin</a></small>
            

        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Good to know, you should mark this answer as correct. So other people can know. Best Regards